# If $f \in L^+$ and $\int f<\infty$ then there exists a null set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

I would like to know if this proof works, since it's a bit different then what I have seen.

It's in Folland , Proposition 2.20 - If $f \in L^+$ 
 and $\int f<\infty$
 then  $\{x:f(x)=\infty\}$
  is a null set

Proof: By theorem 2.10 , there is an increasing sequence of simple functions $\varphi_n$ that converge to $f$ point wise.by the monotone convergence theorem $\int f = \lim \int \varphi_n$.

If $\varphi_n=\infty$ on null set then since the sequence converge to $f$ point wise the result follows.

Now to show that $\varphi_n=\infty$ only on a null set, note that the integral of $\varphi_n=\infty$ becomes $\sum a_j \mu(E_j)$ which by above is less than $\infty$ , hence non of the terms in the sum is $\infty$ , which implies that $a_j$ is not infinite except maybe on a null set which implies that the standard representation of the simple functions is $\infty$ only on a null set (if anywhere).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the proof doesn't work.

If $f_n \to f$ and $\mu(f_n=\infty) = 0$ for all $n$, this does not imply that $\mu(f=\infty)=0$. As a counterexample, consider $f_n = n \mathbf{1}_{[0,1)}$ for all $n$.

A correct argument could go something like this: suppose $A = \{f = \infty\}$ has positive measure. Then
$$
\int f d\mu \geq \int_A f d\mu = \infty
$$
contradicting that $f \in L^1$.

Comment: But how does your counter example work? Fn doesn't converge to any f.

Comment: @Zee, $f_n$ converges to the function that is $\infty$ for all $x$ in $[0,1)$.

Comment: @aortiz we can do this because in the closed real line there is a notion of finite distance between infinity and a real number? Otherwise I don't see how n could be within an epsilon of infinity

Comment: @Zee the notion of convergence is the topological one: a sequence $a_n$ converges to $\infty$ if for every neighborhood $U$ of $\infty$ there exists an $N$ such that $n\ge N$ implies $a_n\in U$